# Order parent records by child record count

Tags: sql, sqlite, sorting, count

I have a table that has a foreign key that points to the id column same table.

```
pages
=====
id      integer primary key autoincrement
name    text
parent  integer
FOREIGN KEY(parent) REFERENCES pages(id)
```

When I do a select query is it possible to sort the results by the number of children records ?

Comment: Do you want to sort by the number of direct children, or the hierarchical ones (children, grandchildren, etc.)?

Comment: @Mureinik's question emphasizes why sample data and desired results are so helpful.

Comment: Order by 1st level children

Answer (score 1):

You could join it with an aggregate query on the child records and sort according to that:

```
SELECT   p.*
FROM     pages p
JOIN     (SELECT   parent, COUNT(*) AS cnt
          FROM     pages
          GROUP BY parent) c ON p.id = c.parent
ORDER BY c.cnt
```

Answer (score 1):

You could compute the count of children with a correlated subquery and sort according to that:

```
SELECT id, name
FROM pages
ORDER BY (SELECT count(*)
          FROM pages AS p2
          WHERE p2.parent = pages.id);
```